# IDE to develop AJAX (AngularJs and PHP)

Tags: php, ide, angularjs, debugging, ajax

I am looking for an IDE which has only one "must have" feature.

I want to develop an AJAX app, with AngularJs on the client side and PHP on the server side.

Is there an IDE which will let me breakpoint both sets of code and run until one or the other hits a breakpoint (server is on`localhost`)?

I would prefer a gratis solution, but am willing to pay. Windows or Linux, please.

Any profession PHP developers here? What do the pros use?

---

[Update] No feedback on this one :-(

So far, the best that I can do is to use my IDE of choice for the AngularJs ([Brackets](http://brackets.io/), YMMW) and then use [Chrome Logger](https://craig.is/writing/chrome-logger) (you might prefer [FirePHP](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-debug-php-using-firefox-with-firephp/)).

Chrome logger lets my PHP write to the Chrome developer's console.

Unfortunately, this is "debug by printf()" and rather a pain (but still a Buddhasend). I continue to seek a solution which will allow me to breakpoint both ([this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/1e49j7/is_there_a_way_to_set_debugging_breakpoints/) seems useful).

---

**PLEASE** only answer this is you have experience with what you are recommending. Thank you